# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python-2.7

I am completely new to python and am having some trouble getting to grips with this stuff. I keep getting the aforementioned error message corresponding to line 14 and onwards (starting with p=) in the code below. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
file = open('random.txt','r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

import pandas

colnames = ['x', 'y', 'e']
data = pandas.read_sv('random.txt', names=colnames)

x = data.x.tolist()
y = data.x.tolist()
e = data.x.tolist()

p = [sum(1/int(a**2) for a in e)]
q = [sum(b/int(a**2) for b, a in zip(x, e))]
r = [sum(c/int(a**2) for c, a in zip(y, e))]
s = [sum(b**2/int(a**2) for b, a in zip(x, e))]
t = [sum(b*c/int(a**2) for c, b, a in zip(y, x, e))]
delta = p*s - q**2

a = (r*s - q*t)/delta
b = (p*t - q*r)/delta

import math
Ua = math.sqrt(s/delta)
Ub = math.sqrt(p/delta)

print('a', 'b', 'Ua', 'Ub')
```

Comment: `e` is a string, so so will `a`. You then attempt to raise `a` to a power, but that doesn't make any sense, since it's a string. You're going to need to explain what you want it to do, since your code doesn't make much sense right now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `data.x.tolist()` returns a list of strings. You must cast each item to `float` or `int` before doing mathematical operations:

```
x = [float(a) for a in data.x.tolist()]
y = [float(a) for a in data.x.tolist()]
e = [float(a) for a in data.x.tolist()]
```

Hope it helps.